# Is it possible to edit tags with cmus?

Tags: tags, ogg, cmus

Is it at all possible to edit tags for `.ogg` files with [cmus](http://cmus.sourceforge.net)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No but - quoting from the feature list - [it] `Can run external commands for the currently selected files (tag-editor for example)`.

You can bind for example:

```
bind common ^E run your-tag-editor {}
```

So when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> in the `common` context, `cmus` will open `your-tag-editor` expanding `{}` to the currently selected files.

Comment: Do you know if cmus supports Vorbis Comments?

Comment: I don't know and can't try right now but the man says: `For vorbis style tags (for example in ogg vorbis and flac files), the special-name tag is ALBUMARTIST and the mark-as-compilation tag is COMPILATION. Vorbis tags names are case insensitive.`

Comment: @cYrus, can you suggest any good command line mp3 tag editor?

Comment: @th1rdey3, I ended up using Ex Falso since I couldn't find any suitable command-line alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on cYrus's answer, I use `id3tool` as the mp3 tag editor, and use the `push` cmus command to dynamically supply the tag type and tag value in the cmus command line.

Set the keybinding:

```
:bind common ^T push run id3tool {}
```

Then run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> when you have a song selected that you want to tag.  That will populate the cmus command line with `:run id3tool {}`, and you can fill in the rest of the id3tool command.

For example, this sets the artist of the selected song to "Action Bronson".

```
:run id3tool {} -r "Action Bronson"
```